# Is the computation precise in 64-bit floating point

Tags: floating-point, precision, numerical-methods

Let's say I have probabilities between 0.1 and 0.2(10,000 of them), and I want to store the result, which is the multiplication of all these probabilities in the 64-bit floating point? Is it a reliable computation?

Comment: You'll have to define more precisely what "reliable" means.

Comment: I think good/precise in quality.

Comment: That's still extremely vague.  How good is good?  Can you quantify the accuracy that you require?  How many probabilities will you be multiplying?

Comment: My bad. I forgot to add the number. Just updated the question.

Comment: You should tell us for what reason you want to perform this unusual computation. And what you mean by *precise* and by *reliable*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not work.  If you multiply together 10000 numbers, all less than 0.2, the result will be less than `0.2^10000` which is about `1e-7000`.  The smallest positive number that can be represented in 64-bit double precision floating point is about `2.2e-308` so you will underflow by several thousand orders of magnitude.  If you try this you'll just get the result `0.0`.

You may want to add their logs instead.

Comment: Detail: "The smallest positive number ...  64-bit double ... about 2.2e-308"  is more like the smallest _normal_ number .  The smallest `double` is often 4.9...e-324, a sub-normal value.  Still, your overall point is valid.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yes, denomals buy you a few orders of magnitude (with correspondingly reduced precision) but don't get us anywhere near close enough for this problem.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: who cares about denorms ? (that's a true question)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Fair to post that as an SO question. One of the original issues it that without sub-normals, `d = a - b` can lead to `a != b && d == 0`.